How to navigate to a new screen, the new screen will overlap the BottomNavigationView
My application is using BottomNavigationView, how can I make it so that when navigating to a new screen, that screen will overlap the BottomNavigationView? Except for hiding the BottomNavigationView when navigating to a new direction. Same as below:
Home
Detail

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
